# gitolite howto allow full access to all branches, but restrict for a specific set

Tags: gitolite

I want to configure gitolite so that

1. Developers cannot push to master and stage1
2. Developers can do RW operations to all other branches (any name they want)

The best thing I came up with is this:

```
repo foo bar

    RW        = @developers
    R  master = @developers
    R  stage1 = @developers
```

But the first rule gives developers full access to all branches.
So how can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Following this example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gitolite/push$20on$20branches%7Csort:relevance/gitolite/ihvnevyF_Kk/Js5O_4tdAiAJ), the order of those [access rules](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#rules) should work (normal then VREF):

```
-  master = @developers
-  stage1 = @developers
RW        = @developers
```

See "[access control rule matching](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#access-control-rule-matching)" for the exact access control rule application recipe.

And since gitolite 3.6.1, you can trace this logic quickly and easily:

```
gitolite access -s foo adeveloper W any
```

More generally, your initial setting should work:

As commented by [Mort](https://stackoverflow.com/users/600360/mort), there is no VREF rules here, only **["refex" rules](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#refex)** as they apply to real refs in the repo

Since no refex is supplied, it defaults to `refs/.*`.

Comment: I have to replace the "R" with "-", otherweise I get: remote: WARNING: doesn't make sense to supply a ref ('refs/heads/master') for 'R' rule

Comment: @Nathan OK. From the doc, your initial order was the right one. I have edited my answer to add the relevant documentation. What a `gitolite access -s foo adeveloper W any` would return for you?

Comment: @Nathan So you had to use deny rules? (`-`)?

Comment: @VonC are you sure that's the right order? Surely that gives `@developers` access to everything. The first matching successful rule gives them RW access to anything. I think you want to put the denies first. Also, these are not VREF rules, they are "refex" rules as they apply to real refs in the repo; VREF rules actually have "VREF" in them as they are not real refs, just _virtual_ ones.

Comment: @Mort Considering http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#access-control-rule-matching, there is a second check for "push" operations, where the deny rule should apply.

Comment: @Mort But yes, I can see the rules are examined *in sequence* http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#c1c2. I just tested and reverted the order.

Comment: @VonC, the `W` in `RW` gets tested by the push operation. Rules _are_ examined in sequence, but as you see by that diagram, once a successful rule allowing an operation is encountered, the "ALLOW Access" state is entered.